# unique id to each cell in android table

Tags: java, android

I have an android table with buttons as the table elements. I want to assign an unique id to each cell(button) such that when I click on particular cell(button) it should return respective id. Please help me how to do this. Sample code would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Just add an `android:id="@+id/unique_id_x_y"` to your buttons, being x and y the column and row number, respectively

Comment: Why don't you use tag to store unique information of that view. It is better compare to creating unique id to view.

Answer (score 0):

use in xml

```
 android:id ="@+id/your_id"
```

or programmatically

```
yourelement.setId(yourID);
```

example

```
  button.setId(01);
```

where button is the object of Button class

Answer (score 0):

if you have hard coded buttons in xml then set id in xml itself like this:

```
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_row_col"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="button1"
        />
```

if you are adding it dynamically then:

```
 Button newBtn=new Button();
   newBtn.setText("button");
   newBtn.setId(yourId);  //here setid to your button
```